# Exception Handling: How to organize my code for specific question?

Tags: python, file, exception

So, I'm currently taking an intro to programming class and we started learning about files and exception handling. I'm having trouble with a question that is based on exception handling.

This question is asking me to read the data from `population.txt`, checks to make sure the file exists and is in the right format (if it isn’t throw an appropriate exception), calculates the combined population of the countries in the text file and prints that total.

This is how the file looks like

```
Afghanistan:32738376
Albania:3619778
Algeria:33769669
Jamaica:2804332
Japan:127288419
Paraguay:6831306
Peru:29180899
Philippines:92681453
Pitcairn Islands:48
Tajikistan:7211884
Turkmenistan:5179571
Zambia:11669534
Zimbabwe:12382920
```

I did something like this. As you can see, I am confused as to how to organize my code, but I know I am onto something. Should I have put the if statements under the except clause? How would you guys have done this?

```
try:
    infile=open("population..txt","r")
    for line in infile:
        line=line.rstrip()
        wordList=line.split(":")
        if type(word[0])!=str:
            raise ValueError("This is not a string")
        elif type(word[1])!=int:
            raise ValueError("This not an integer")
        else:
            pass
except IOError as e:
    print(e)
else:
finally:
    infile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions need to be raised inside a `try` block to be catched. That part of the code is correct. You need however to catch all the different exceptions that may be raised and definitely in this case *you do not need to raise them by yourself:*

```
try:
    totpopulation = 0

    with open("population.txt","r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line=line.rstrip()
            wordList=line.split(":")
            popul = int(wordList[1])
            totpopulation += popul
    print("Total population:", totpopulation)

except (OSError, ValueError, IndexError) as e:
    print(e)
```

As you see here the `raise` statement is not used explicitly: exceptions are raised by the built-in functions when their argument is not valid:

- `OSError` is the class of the exception raised by `open` if the file does not exists.
- `ValueError` is the class of the exception raised by `int(wordList[1])` if the string `wordList[1]` cannot be converted to an integer.
- `IndexError` is raised by `wordlist[1]` if the length of `wordlist` is 0, hence Index out of range. It may happen if a line is not splitted because `':'` is missing.

It seems to me that you do not need other exception classes in this code. However the list of all the built-in exceptions is in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError), if you wish to know what other exceptions are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to avoid exceptions while reading data from the file.

```
with open('text_file', 'r') as f:
    # pass your code there
```

Comment: The with statement does not "avoid" exceptions. They are still raised if something goes wrong, and need to be catched.